# How to go about an 'overridable' method in an interface driven plugin

Tags: c#, interface, overriding

I have an app that accepts plugins using a shared library full of interface classes, but would also like to define some static methods to interact with them that can be overridden by the plugin. I understand the limitations in C# that preclude me from just defining the 'override-able' virtual method as static, but need to know what approach to take nonetheless.

And before anybody marks this as duplicates of 'Declare virtual inside static' questions, I have read all that I can find and none show a workaround for achieving the same results especially considering that I am using interfaces.

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    int MyNum {get;}
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int NewMyNum(this IMyClass class)
    {
        return class.MyNum * 2;
    }
}
public class FirstClass : IMyClass
{
    int MyNum {get {return 5;}}
}
public class AnotherClass : IMyClass
{
    int MyNum {get {return 5;}}
    public override NewMyNum(this IMyClass class)
    {
        return class.MyNum * 3;
    }
}

public class Main()
{
    IMyClass AClassObj = new IMyClass();
    console.writeLine(AClassObj.NewMyNum());
    IMyClass BClassObj = new IMyClass();
    console.writeLine(BClassObj.NewMyNum());
}
```

I know this is nowhere near compile-able code, but I hope it illustrates what I am trying to achieve without me posting hundreds of line of code.

Comment: Did you mean to replace `IMyClass` in the `new` expressions in `Main` with `FirstClass` and `AnotherClass`?

Comment: Just a mix-up, Main() in my real world app is just your standard "iterate list of types found in DLLs and initialize them" plugin loader.